# npgsql.dll Authentication method not supported (Received: 10)

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

win7, postgreSQL 14, VS2013, C#

I get an error when connecting in app (npgsql.dll) npgsql v3.2.6-3

Exception: Authentication method not supported (Received: 10)

which version npgsql.dll and where can I download for Windows 7 to fix this error?